# Can't select any vertex in an object!

Tags: mesh, vertices, selection-tools

I started using blender a few days ago, and decided to make a dog, so I'll learn how to use blender properly.

One night I saved the file and got off the computer. A few hours later I opened the file, but couldn't select any vertex, it's like they're not there (although it shows me the grid). I am in vertex and edit mode.

[image: dog mesh]

Comment: Are you sure you are in vertex selection mode. In edit mode you have three distinct selection modes, Vertex, Edge and Face. Try hitting Ctrl + Tab while in edit mode to switch between them

Comment: You may have another object selected. Make sure your dog mesh is selected in the outliner. If it's not, then vertex select won't respond.

Comment: Tnx for the help. The dog wasnt selected it the outliner. Tnx again.

Answer (score 3):

K_Horeman's answer helped me fix it:

https://blenderartists.org/t/noob-weird-selection-issues-cant-select-vertices-of-a-mesh-in-edit-mode/622979/2

"If it’s selected in orange with no vertices when you’re in edit mode, it is a separate object. You’ll have to go to edit mode on that object. You can only be in edit mode on one object at a time."

I didn't have the correct mesh selected in the Viewer (top-right) before entering Edit mode. So I highlighted all 4 objects you see in the picture, and I can select their vertices.

Comment: *You can only be in edit mode on one object at a time.*

Answer (score 2):

You need to click on *Show Overlays* next to *Show Gizmos* and *Toggle X-Ray*